# Chart for Cache Hits and Misses donot lower's for more options

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, caching, charts

I am making a Cache Simulation Project, for whom i have calculated all the Hit's, Misses and their ratio's. Now i want to plot these Hit, Misses in a Bar chart.
I have used the Bar Chart control in VS 2010.
I want three bars one for each.

```
1. Total Addresss Read
2. Hits
3. Misses
```

I have also calculated the Hit Limit and Miss Limit as follows
I have given all this code in a button click event

```
float hit_limit;
            float miss_limit;
            int i;
            hit_limit = (hit / total) * 30;
            miss_limit =(miss / total) * 30;

            chartt.Series["Total"].Points.AddXY(0, 30);
            chartt.Series["Hit"].Points.AddXY(1,hit_limit);
            chartt.Series["Misses"].Points.AddXY(2, miss_limit);
```

The Hits and misses are calculated dynamically in my project from the user's selected combo box values. When at first chart is made, its bar's doesnot lower's for the second execution of program.
i.e., The first hit limit and miss limit remains a constant beginning point, from where these bars cannot revert back for more user selected options

But this is not working, Any ideas on how can i achieve this task